# Event based design - Futures, Promises vs Akka Persistence

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I have multiple use cases which require predefined events to be fired based on a certain user actions.

e.g. let's say when `NewUser` is created in the application, it'll have to call `CreateUserInWorkflowSystem` and `FireEmailToTheUser` asynchronously. There are many other business cases of this nature where events will be predefined based on a usecase. I can use Promises/Futures to model these events as below

```
if 'NewUser' then 
    call `CreateUserInWorkflowSystem` (which will be Future based API)
    call `FireEmailToTheUser` (which will be Future based API)
if 'FileImport' then
   call `API3` (which will be Future based call)
   call `API4` (which will be Future based call)
```

All those `Future` calls will have to log failures somewhere so failed calls can be retried etc. Note `NewUser` call won't be waiting for those `Futures` (events per say) to complete.

That was using plain `Futures/Promises` APIs. However I am thinking [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html) will be an appropriate fit here and blocking calls can still run into `Futures`. With Akka persistence, handling failure will be easy as it provides it out of box etc. I understand Akka persistence is still in experimental stage but that doesn't seem to be a big concern as typesafe generally keeps these new frameworks into experimental state before promoting into future release etc. (same was true with Macros). Given these requirements do you think `Futures/Promises` or Akka persistence is a better fit here?

Answer (score 1):

This is an **opinion based** question - not the best type to ask on SO. Anyway, trying to answer.

It really depends what you are more **comfortable** with and what your **requirements** are. Do you need to scale the system later beyond a **single JVM** - use Akka. Do you want to keep it more **simple** - use Futures.

If you use Futures you can store all state and actions to execute in a job queue/db. It's quite reasonable.

If you use Akka Persistence then obviously it will help you with persistence. Akka will help to perform **supervison**, recovery and retries easier. If your `CreateUserInWorkflowSystem` action fails result is propagated to supervising actor which probably restarts the failed actor and makes it retry for N times. If your supervising actor fails then his supervisor will do the right thing, or eventually the whole app will crash which is good. With Futures you would have to implement this mechanism yourself and make sure that application can crash when needed.

If you have completely **independent actions** then Futures and Actors sound about the same. If you have to chain actions and **compose** them, then using Futures will be a somewhat more natural thing to do: **for comprehensions**, etc. In Akka you would have to wait for a message and based on a type of a message perform next action.

Try to mock a simple implementation using both and compare what you like/dislike given your particular application requirements. Overall, **both choices are good**, but I'm slightly leaning towards actors in this case.